# How to instrument java classes for Code Coverage Reports on Junit Tests? (JCov, Clover or any other tool?)

Tags: java, code-coverage

How to instrument java classes for Code Coverage Reports on Junit Tests? (JCov, Clover or any other tool?)

I am unable to generate java code coverage on java classes (eg java.lang.String), so help/advice would be greatly appreciated on the following:

1) JCov: Additional documentation for explaining how to generate code coverage reports using openJDK JCov tool? I am unable to instrument any classes and is limited information in FAQs on the openJDKtools Jcov site: wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcov

2) Clover:  How to instrument Java classes? Other libraries (eg apache) and my own classes are instrumented and coverage reports are generated fine, but not for java classes? (openclover.org)

3) Another code coverage tool that would work on java classes? I have tried these tools:
EvoSuite but this cannot cover java classes. 
dJunit doesn't seem to work on java classes either. 
Emma fails on bootstrap java classes, eg java.lang.String. 
I haven't tried these yet: Cobertura, JaCoCo.

I also want to perform the same test and produce coverage for both Java1.4 and Java8.

Thanks any help.

Jeff

Comment: You want to measure the test coverage of classes such as `java.lang.String`?!? Why? Are you developing code for the OpenJDK project? But even then, why measure the coverage of `java.lang.String`?

Comment: Our software and framework is moving from a java 1.4 to 8, which is under modular & general tests. Release notes and Junit results on Randoop test code, have shown some small differences in java 1.4 & 8 coding, eg java.lang.Long constant values.

To prove adequate coverage, we wanted to produce comparable (and hopefully equivalent) coverage results for the 65 java classes & 280 methods that we currently use on java 1.4.
We have been unable to produce coverage results. It seems that the coverage software is unable to instrument the java classes under test.

Comment: Ok... I am not sure why you feel that measuring the coverage of JRE classes is needed (seems like a questionable idea to me), but regular code coverage tools for Java do not support that. The `.class` files cannot be instrumented on disk at build time because they are inside `rt.jar`. And since many of these classes (String, Long, etc.) are loaded by the JVM *before* a Java agent (used by modern coverage tools such as JaCoCo) can even install a `ClassfileTransformer` (which applies instrumentation), they cannot be instrumented by on-the-fly (runtime-based) tools either.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.